# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: .. A::test()

Tags: c++, visual-studio, lnk2019, linker-errors

In visual studio, one project has the Class A definition.

in header file A.h:

```
class A{

public:
   void test();
}

in A.cpp file:

void A::test()
{

}
```

no error here.

But another project when I try to use the test function of A in file B.cpp, there is a link error:

> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: .. A::test() ...

I think here is nothing to do with the namespace. And the other classes defined in the same files as Class A (in A.h and A.cpp) have no problem using in B.cpp. What the possible reasons could be for my situation?

Thanks

Comment: You wrote "But another project when I try to use the test function of A"... Is that really a completely separate project?  If so, are you building this project as a library and linking that library into your other project?

Comment: Presumably you don't link with the object file containing the test() function.

Comment: But other classes in the same file as class A have no problem.

Comment: Post the real code.

Comment: My fault, I forget the __declspec(dllexport) before class A

Comment: So, the code in `B.cpp` can see everything in `A.h`, and link to everything in `A.cpp` except `A::test()`, if I understand this correctly.  Then, what is different about either `A` or `A::test()`?